# Databind through multiple .xaml files

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to make a standard UI element (Content control) in my Resource dictionary so i can easily create multiple circular graphs on my user control by just sending the data to it through a property.

I now want to bind the Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" property of <lvc:PieChart > (part of the Livecharts.WPF NuGet package) to my resourceDictionary item. That way i hope i can keep the lay-out of the graph the same and just send the data by assigning the correct property name.

Xaml code to draw the graph (lets say Window.xaml for further reference):

```
<ContentControl x:Name="CircGraphCrypto" Style="{StaticResource circularGraphStocks}" local:IconProperties.CircGraphSeriesBinding="SeriesCollection"/>
```

The local is where I would pass the name for the SeriesCollection which is in the back-end code of the Xaml. The name is in this case SeriesCollection.

Resource dictionary code:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AutomationProject"
xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf" 
   
<!-- Circular graph stocks -->
    <Style x:Key="circularGraphStocks" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource borderRounded}">
                        <Grid Margin="5,10,5,5">
                            <lvc:PieChart Series="{Binding Path=(local:IconProperties.CircGraphSeriesBinding), Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                        LegendLocation="Right" InnerRadius="10" Margin="5,5,5,5" Foreground="White">
                                <lvc:PieChart.ChartLegend>
                                    <lvc:DefaultLegend BulletSize="20"></lvc:DefaultLegend>
                                </lvc:PieChart.ChartLegend>
                                <lvc:PieChart.DataTooltip>
                                    <lvc:DefaultTooltip BulletSize="20" Foreground="Black"></lvc:DefaultTooltip>
                                </lvc:PieChart.DataTooltip>
                            </lvc:PieChart>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I then try to send a string called "{Binding SeriesCollection}" to the <lvc:PieChart Series="{Binding Path=(local:IconProperties.CircGraphSeriesBinding) as this is how I would define it if all of the creation code was on xaml file that i want to show the graph on. The only thing i don't know is if this will try to get the SeriesCollection data from the backend of the resource dictionary, if it had one, or not. The Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" should come from Window.xaml.cs where i use the content control.

Attached property code:

```
 namespace AutomationProject
{
    public class IconProperties : DependencyObject
    {
        public static DependencyProperty CircGraphSeriesBindingProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CircGraphSeriesBinding", typeof(string), typeof(IconProperties),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

        public static string GetCircGraphSeriesBinding(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            string dataBinding = "{Binding " + (string)obj.GetValue(CircGraphSeriesBindingProperty) + "}";
            MessageBox.Show(dataBinding);
            return dataBinding;
        }

        public static void SetCircGraphSeriesBinding(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CircGraphSeriesBindingProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, you do not need to derive from DependencyObject in order to declare an attached property. Better declare `public static class IconProperties { ... }`

Comment: Besides that, it is wrong to return anything else than `(string)obj.GetValue(CircGraphSeriesBindingProperty)` from the getter of the attached property. The Binding expression string makes no sense at all, because such an expression would have to be parsed by a XAML parser in order to be converted into an actual Binding.

Comment: Hmm i am new to all of this and find binding pretty difficult to fully understand. All the different solutions I see only make it worse i feel like :). Thanks for the information. I will try to implement this tomorrow. Do you also know in what direction i should look on google to solve my problem by any chance? Should I be returning a Binding instead of a string saying binding?

Comment: @JorisBeuls You seem to have misunderstood Xaml syntax. You can write it like text in Xaml but can not treat it as string value. If you still want to use attached property, the type should be `SeriesCollection` instead of string. How to wire up the property and actual data is up to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately made custom user controls(WPF) and this very easily made it possible to do what i needed. Normal dependency binding using propdp is sufficient.

```
    public partial class StockSingleDisplay : UserControl
    {    
        public string Title
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Title.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(StockSingleDisplay), new PropertyMetadata("Test"));
     }
```

Binding to the code behind:

```
<UserControl Name="StockSingleDisplayWindow">
<Grid>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=StockSingleDisplayWindow}"/>
</Grid>
```

Xaml code to show it (Namespace is the folder that holds the user control):

```
xmlns:CustomStocks="clr-namespace:AutomationProject.CustomControls.Stocks"
<CustomStocks:StockSingleDisplay Title="Displayed Text"/>
```